# How Does WordPress Handle Upgrades?

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, ftp, upgrade

Can anyone describe the [pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) for how WordPress handles its upgrades? As in, you go into WordPress admin and choose to upgrade the version of WordPress.

I mean, does it use FTP APIs locally? Does it send credentials to another host which reconnects back with FTP APIs? Does it download files with Curl? Does it polyfill if a given API isn't there and go another route? Does it test file permissions to see which API to use?

I've got a client who wants something like this built into a web application unrelated to WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look it `wp-admin/includes/update.php` and `wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php`

And here for some explanation: http://tech.ipstenu.org/2011/how-the-wordpress-upgrade-works/